# How to insert html code in mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, insert

I have copies text from many html files into one text file/variable  and I wants to insert this data(basically html code) into mysql database. I have tried mysql_real_escape_string. But it is still no working. This is what I am doing :

```
$contentFromHtmlFile=file_get_contents($file);  
$all_html_content.=$contentFromHtmlFile; 
$all_html_content=mysql_real_escape_string($all_html_content);  
$insert_query = "insert into $databasetable (pdf_id,pdf_text_data) values (190,$all_html_content);";

mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is the error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<meta charset=\&quot;utf-8\&quot; />\n\n<div id=\&quot;jpedal\&quot; style=\&quo' at line 1
```

Here link of text I wants to insert: http://pastebin.com/F3BD745h

Comment: You still need to wrap quotes around the data: `'$all_html_content'`

Comment: Don't use mysql_* queries as they are being deprecated (won't exist in future versions) and highly susceptible to sql injection. You should switch your code over to mysqli or PDO, and bind the parameters, which will take care of the escaping of quotes.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern interface like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) supports parameterized queries which makes properly escaping your data a lot easier, and your code way more readable. It also avoids these quotation issues you're having here.

Answer (score 1):

You have put string values inside single quotes:

```
 $insert_query = "insert into $databasetable(pdf_id,pdf_text_data)values(190,'$all_html_content');";
```

P.S:**mysql_** function are depricared , don't use them. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: tip: if all you're doing is copying a wide/long code snippet and changing a few characters, then point out where those characters are. a `'` is easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your variable around single quotes to signify that it's a string (in this case):

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO $databasetable(pdf_id, pdf_text_data)
                 VALUES(190, '$all_html_content');";
                             ^                 ^
```

Also, if you do not need to use the string for searching or any similar operations, I'd recommend converting it an ordinary string with [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode):

```
$contentFromHtmlFile = file_get_contents($file);  
$all_html_content .= $contentFromHtmlFile;  
$all_html_content = base64_encode($all_html_content);
$all_html_content = mysql_real_escape_string($all_html_content);
```

Comment: wut? Why in b64? Data will be larger by 33%

Comment: @bordeux: that's probably some kind of cargo-cult security.